# wp_generate_attachment_metadata returning an empty array

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

I'm writing a Wordpress plugin to download remote images on my blog.

I made a function to upload a remote image locally, then returning its ID.
All seems OK except that

```
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $local_file );
```

returns me an empty array - and it should not.

[wp_generate_attachment_metadata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata) is, among others, responsible of generating the thumbnails of the uploaded image.  But I have no thumbnails created when I run my code.

I checked the values I send to the function and they seems correct : I have an ID and an absolute path to the uploaded file, as documented in the codex.
Still, I can't manage to have my code working :

**$attach_data** should not be empty...

Can anyone help ?

```
function upload_from_remote_url($url,$post_id){

    $url = $this->validate_remote_media_url($url); //check file is not on local server
    if (!$url) return false;

    if ($existing_id = $this->media_already_exists($url)) return $existing_id; //url already has been downloaded

    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $wp_mime_types = wp_get_mime_types();

    //fetch image
    $response = wp_remote_get( $url );

    //get filename without extension
    $filename = basename( $url ); //get filename & extension
    $filename_strip = preg_replace('/\.[^.]*$/', '', $filename); //strip extension

    //get extension from content type,
    //because wp_upload_bits needs an extension and certain url don't have one.

    $file_type = wp_remote_retrieve_header( $response, 'content-type' );
    $extensions = array_search($file_type,$wp_mime_types);
    $extensions_arr = explode('|',$extensions);
    $extension = $extensions_arr[0];

    $new_filename = $filename_strip.'.'.$extension; //full name
    $new_filename = wp_unique_filename($upload_dir['path'], $new_filename); // be sure this name do not exist already

    $uploaded = wp_upload_bits($new_filename, '', wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
    if ($uploaded['error']) return false;

    $local_file = $uploaded['file'];
    $local_filename = basename($local_file);
    $local_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $local_filename, null );

    //Attachment options
    $attachment = array(
        'post_title'=> $local_filename,
        'post_mime_type' => $local_filetype,
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );

    // Add the image to your media library
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $local_file, $post_id );

    if (!$attach_id) return false;

    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $local_file );

    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    //save source link so we do not import several times the same media
    update_post_meta($attach_id, 'grm_source', $url);

    return $attach_id;

}
```

BTW, if any WP gourou had anything to say about this code... I'll be happy to read it, as the WP documentation about uploading files is a bit messy.  I needed some specific stuff here, as being able to retrieve the file extension.  I ended up to this but maybe you have some better ideas !

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem where mime type was missing. Since I use only one mime type, it was fixed by

```
'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg'
```

After that, it was still not updating the metadata, but forcing the update with "wp_update_attachment_metadata" solved the problem:

```
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $file_path);
wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is, what finally fixed it for me:

```
apply_filters('wp_handle_upload', array(
    'file' => $file_path, 
    'url' => $file_url, 
    'type' => $file_type), 
'upload');
```

Explanation: I'm not quite sure why this fixed the error for me, but I assume that this either has something to do with plugins using the wp_handle_upload hook or that the filters add meta-data to the attachment, which otherwise would be missing in the wp_generate_attachment_metadata function.

Full function:

```
function add_to_media_lib($file_url, $file_path, $parent_post_id)
{
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');

// Check the type of tile. We'll use this as the 'post_mime_type'.
$file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($file_url), null);

// Get the path to the upload directory.
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

// Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
$attachment = array(
    'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($file_url),
    'post_mime_type' => $file_type['type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($file_url)),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_parent' => $parent_post_id
);

// Insert the attachment.
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_url, $parent_post_id);

// apply filters (important in some environments)
apply_filters('wp_handle_upload', array('file' => $file_path, 'url' => $file_url, 'type' => $file_type), 'upload');


// Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
if ($attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $file_path)) {
    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
} else {
    echo '<div id="message" class="error"><h1>Failed to create PDF-thumbnail Meta-Data</h1><pre>' . print_r($attach_data) . '</pre></div>';
}

return $attach_id;
}
```

Comment: Does this also create thumbnails for pdf, for me my code is creating thumbnail for images but not for pdf or rar or zip files ?

Answer (score 0):

I know the topic is old but I was facing a similar issue and what worked for me was enabling the **Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions (normally thumbnails are proportional)** under Settings >> Media. I am using the *media_handle_sideload()* function by the way.